# PHP, remove all global variables in the global scope

Tags: php

I want to be able to flush all variables in the global scope using a single function with one call to unset(). I want to keep all the variables that exist in _GET, _POST, _REQUEST, _COOKIE, _SERVER, _ENV, _FILES, _SESSION, and remove only the variables that exist in $GLOBALS[variable]. So say my $GLOBALS contained...

```
<php>
Array
(
[GLOBALS] => Array
*RECURSION*
[_POST] => Array
    (
    )

[var_3] => Array
    (
    )

[_GET] => Array
    (
    )

[_COOKIE] => Array
    (
    )

[_SERVER] => Array
    (
        [HTTPS] => on
        [APPL_MD_PATH] => /docs/
        [APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH] => /www/docs/
        [INSTANCE_ID] => 1
        [INSTANCE_META_PATH] => /
        [LOGON_USER] => 
        [REQUEST_URI] => /test.php
        [URL] => /test.php
        [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /www/docs/test.php
        [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /www/docs/
        [PHP_SELF] => /test.php
        [HTTP_HOST] => localhost
    )

[_ENV] => Array
    (
    )

[_FILES] => Array
    (
    )

[_REQUEST] => Array
    (
    )

[var_2] => Array
    (
    )

[var_3] => Array
    (
    )
)
</php>
```

I would want to flush var_1, var_2 and var_3.

Comment: Why do you require one `unset` call?

Answer (score 5):

You can edit your `php.ini` file and set:

```
variables_order = ""
```

> ...Setting to "" means no superglobals will be set. [0]

[0] http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order