# How to disable arrays in $_GET and $_POST in php?

Tags: php, query-string

How to disable arrays in $_GET and $_POST in php?

Because arrays break some of my apps, I cannot change all of them to be compatible with arrays;

So, if a user requests:

```
example.com/script.php?examplearray[]=value1&examplearray[]=vavlue2
```

Even in POST requests, you can do the same thing, so how can I disable them as they break stuff such as `htmlentities()`

Comment: You can't disable something like that because it's not in your control. You can perform a check to see if it's an array and then do whatever you feel necessary in that case.

Comment: @El_Vanja, or how can I get the raw query string from POST? Like `example=1&example2=2&example3=3`. I am able to get the query string from GET using the QUERY_STRING env, but I do not know about POST.

Comment: Why do you feel you need it in that form?

Comment: @El_Vanja, I just need it because I do not like the square brackets at all. Handling arrays in between 1000+ lines of code is too hard! but I can do a replace and replace all the $_POST to $_CUSTOM_POST which I create... But I do not know how to get the raw POST data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP, remove all global variables in the global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302869/php-remove-all-global-variables-in-the-global-scope)

Comment: Raw post data...? Why would you need anything except the `$_POST` variable? You could write a function that replaces any array values with some default of your own choosing and call it at the beginning of any script that uses it. Or you could display an error page to the user if you detect an array. Or something else entirely. But I see no purpose in trying to get the data in a way different from simply accessing `$_POST`.